# NullReferenceException when loading MVC view with partial data in the model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

A new problem for me... When I load the page, Visual Studio highlights the following line with a NullReferenceException

> Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

I have confirmed that the targeted cshtml file does exist - this new view isn't the only one that uses it.

Any assistance in identifying and solving the problem will be greatly appreciated.

I'm getting to this page with the following jquery (it's on a `<button>` control):

```
<h2 data-item="@Model.Thread.Id" class="thread-name">@Model.Thread.Name</h2>

<script>
    $(".reply_to_thread").on("click", function () {
        var ThreadId = $(".thread-name").attr("data-item");
        location.href = "/Post/New?threadId=" + ThreadId;
    });
</script>
```

The page is supposed to use a Querystring value to allow a user to write a response to other content. The Querystring tells the system what content this new post should be associated with.

The user can also quote another user's post optionally. In this case, the system writes a quote of the other user's post into the new user's post to present it on the form. Otherwise the form should just load with an empty textarea where the user will supply the content for his/her new post.

```
public ActionResult New(int threadId, int quoted = 0)
{
    // Check that the user has a valid login - if not, redirect to login page.
    if (!CheckUserCookie()) return RedirectToAction("Login", "Home", new { newpost = "true", thread = threadId });

    // get medatada for the new post - user should not be able to edit this
    int UserId = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Cookies["Fudge"]["uid"]);
    bool Banned = Convert.ToBoolean(Request.Cookies["Fudge"]["ub"]);

    // don't allow the user to post if banned
    if (Banned) return RedirectToAction("Home", "Banned");

    // user is allowed to post, build the model and render the view
    NewPostViewModel Model = new NewPostViewModel
    {
        User = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == UserId),
        Thread = db.Threads.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == threadId)
    };

    // if this post is a reply quoting another post, add the quoted post to the
    // new post's content - get it by the post id
    if (quoted >= 1)
    {                
        Markdown Markdown = new Markdown();
        Post Parent = db.Posts.Include(t => t.User).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == quoted);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendLine(String.Format("> *In reply to {0}*", Parent.User.Username));
        sb.AppendLine(Parent.Content);

        Model.Content = Markdown.Transform(sb.ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        // this quote isn't in reply to an existing post
        Model.Content = String.Empty;
    }

    return View(Model);
}
```

Here's a screenshot:

[image: NullReferenceException on MVC Layout]

Comment: Some times razor may mark the wrong line when exception occors in .cshtml file, ensure that the model is not null and there is values for Model.Thread.Id...

Comment: You could change the Layout to `Null` temporarily to validate what @Ziyad suggests.

Comment: Actually I don't think I need to. Looking at some Watch values, I think I missed a .Include() somewhere in my queries. Otherwise I will change the Layout as recommended and report back

Comment: Yup, that did it... Thanks though @Ziyad your comment led me to check the model more closely so I found the issue in there.

Comment: Glad you solve it :)